# Regex Match All Characters Between Tags on nth occurrence

Tags: regex, html-parsing

I need to match text between two tags, but starting at a specific occurrence of the tag.

Imagine this text:

```
Some long <br> text goes <br> here. And some <br> more can <br> go here.<br>
```

In my example, I would like to match **here. And some**.
I successfully matched the text between the first occurrence (between the first and second *br* tags) with:

```
<br>(.*?)<br>
```

But I am looking for the text in the next match (which would be between the second and third *br* tags). This is probably more obvious than I realize, but Regex is not my strong suite.

Comment: What is your platform? And, more importantly, what is your justification for using regular expressions to parse HTML?

Comment: I am using a data scraping extension in chrome, and I am gathering address data that is stored in a single <td> element separated by <br> for each address component. This will change from site to site, so I just need a quick way to get what I need on any given site and then move on.

Comment: So you are using what's probably the most capable HTML parser *on the planet* and yet you think that regex is a quick way of moving on? If you were using a platform without a proper HTML parser (text editor, maybe), that would count. But in Chrome, it doesn't. I'd show you a sold way of solving this if you share your code so far.

Comment: I am using the [Web Scrapper](http://webscraper.io/) extension. It successfully grabs the text I am looking at, but then it shows up as: `<a action="some_action" class="some_name" recnum="1" href="javascript:void(0);">My Company Title</a><br> <strong class="">(999) 999-9999</strong><br> First Avenue Lane<br> Somwhere, II 00000<br>`

Comment: Looks like a job for the [`text` selector](http://webscraper.io/documentation#text-selector). It will convert `<br>` to `\n` internally and also translate all possible HTML character entities to actual characters. Splitting plain text on `\n` afterwards is a good use of regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just extend your regex:

```
<br>(.*?)<br>(.*?)<br>
```

or, for an unlimited number of matches, and trimming the spaces:

```
<br>\s*(.*?)(?=\s*<br>)
```

**EDIT:** Now that I see that you are parsing an HTML document, be aware that regular expressions may not be the best tool for that job, especially if your parsing requirements are complex.

Comment: Please don't give regex-HTML-parsing advice. It's more helpful to teach people how to use a parser than throwing regex at them that work for the example given and inevitably blow up in real life.

Comment: @Tomalak When I responded, the HTML tag was missing. But I'll add a comment to my response.